# Batch file to ask for session ID in tsdiscon?

Tags: session, batch-file, terminal-server

Pardon my very broad question here guys. I don't ever really do much coding (at all) and was hoping you guys could help me out. Basically what I would like to do is have an end user run a script that asks them what Session ID they would like to disconnect. This will be used in conjunction with the "tsdiscon" command.

So the script would open > Ask for session ID > disconnect that session ID.

Seems pretty simple but like I said, I never do any of this. Thank you guys for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very robust, but try this:

**sidkill.bat**

```
@echo off
cls
set /p sid=Enter Session ID:
echo Disconnecting session %sid%
tsdiscon %sid%
```

Comment: Hey hey! That's actually perfect. I knew it would be something pretty simple. Seeing it that simple makes me feel a little stupid, I won't lie.

Comment: No worries.  Welcome to SO.